# How to get facebook pending friend requests through fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm working on getting pending requests by fql. I've set up "read_requests" permission and used following fql:

```sql
SELECT uid_from,
               message
FROM.   friend_request
WHERE. uid_to = me()
```

But it doesn't work and I do not get anything.

Comment: Are you sure you have pending friend requests? most users will very rarely have pending friend requests, and will accept or reject them shortly after they arrive

Answer (score 1):

1. You need the `read_requests` permission  for any friend requests that are sent by or to the current session user.
2. You can read a list of friend requests **sent to** the current user -

```sql
    SELECT time,
           message
    FROM friend_request
    WHERE uid_to = me()
```

Or, you can check the status of any friend request **sent by** the current user, but you have to provide the id of the user to whom the request was sent. You cannot retrieve all friend requests sent by the current user -

```sql
    SELECT time,
           message
    FROM friend_request
    WHERE uid_from = me()
    AND uid_to = ID
```